# Run MonoDevlop program from command prompt

Tags: c#, monodevelop, command-prompt

I've written a program in MonoDevlop that gets some user input then prints/writes it (using `console.writeline`) but when I just click run it writes the line I told it to print but I am not able to type any input

How would I run my program from the command prompt so that I can enter some input
I am using Windows. Code is below if you need it for some reason.

```
using System;

public class Hellow{

static void Main(){
    Console.WriteLine("this is a test line");
    string apple = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(apple);

}


 }
```

Comment: You just need to navigate to the directory of the executable and run it using the command prompt. Or were you looking to do it explicityly within MonoDevelop? Do you know where MonoDevelop stores it's builds?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "MonoDevelop" program, MonoDevelop is an editor..

Comment: I would rather do it within MonoDevlop as it seems faster but if that can not be done how would I make my program into and executable

Comment: MonoDevelop will be creating a .Net executable from your code when you hit 'build' or 'run'. This will be stored somewhere (usually within a bin folder within your project directory somewhere). So you will have an executable already :).

Comment: CodeBeard
Thank you, your comment solved the problem(sort of, when I press enter on the command prompt it closes out, but it still works)
I dont know if it would be appropriate for me to answer my own question but I dont want to leave this unanswered and you did no post an answer just a comment. I am new to this forum so can you tell me if it is acceptable to answer your own question if someone else answered it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks CodeBeard. Your answer solved my question.

"*MonoDevelop will be creating a .Net executable from your code when you hit 'build' or 'run'. This will be stored somewhere (usually within a bin folder within your project directory somewhere). So you will have an executable already*"